# H2 DataBase: Have you ever feel that H2 Database Can Inconsistent sometimes?

Tags: hibernate, h2

I'm trying to debug a code where I'm getting an Error: When I Go to DB and check the Table ConnectionInfo for Particular id "258" I couldn't find any Data. I have check it more than 10 times and every time I see data is not Present. I'm not sure What Exactly is Happening.
We are using Spring+ Hibernate+H2 DB

```
    2024-02-05 19:53:19 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:137 - SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
2024-02-05 19:53:19 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:142 - Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK__CONNECTION_INFO__DEPLOYED_COMPONENT__DEPLOYED_COMP: DEPLOY_CENTER.CONNECTION_INFO FOREIGN KEY(DEPLOYED_COMP) REFERENCES DEPLOY_CENTER.DEPLOYED_COMPONENT(DEPLOYED_COMPONENT_ID) (CAST(258 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
delete from deploy_center.deployed_component where DEPLOYED_COMPONENT_ID=? [23503-212]
2024-02-05 19:53:19 INFO  AbstractBatchImpl:208 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2024-02-05 19:53:20 ERROR QuickDeployConfigService:137 - DCXXE000could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FK__CONNECTION_INFO__DEPLOYED_COMPONENT__DEPLOYED_COMP:
```